# ASP.net/HTML how to customize URL

Tags: html, asp.net, url

I have a website when I open my frontpage on my website it goes `www.website.com` and when I press `Contact` it goes `www.website.com/Contact` That's fine, but when I go back to my Frontpage it display `www.website.com/Default` How do I remove "Default" I want it to only write `www.website.com` when I press my logo or redirect to my frontpage.

SiteLayout.cshtml

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Website Title</title>
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title"><a href="~/Default"><img src="Images/Website White.png" height="50" /></a>- My Website Text</p>
            </div>
```

Default.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
}

@section featured {
    <title>Website Title</title>
<section class="featured">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <hgroup class="title">
            <h2></h2>
        </hgroup>
        <p>
            A lot of text
        </p>
    </div>
</section>
}
```

let me know if you need more code.

Comment: you could look into [URL rewriting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx). Complex but useful.

Comment: Exactly you can use href="~/" which will definitely take you to the default without the controller/action name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Default` part of the URL is coming out because it is in your link back to the homepage, I'm guessing this one `<a href="~/Default">`.

As the root URL links to the Default page anyway, you can just remove 'Default' part from your `href`, in order to go the root without the path:

```
<a href="~/">
```

Aside from this the alternative is to redirect `www.website.com/Default` to `www.website.com` in your server-side code.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that, but now I do. Thanks!